# How can I select only the anchors within a div by id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Here is the code I'm using right now.

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $('.answer').hide();

});
$('.question').click(function () {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#a"+currentId.substr(1)).fadeToggle("fast", function () {
  });
});+
$('#show_hide').click(function () {
  $(".answer").fadeToggle("fast", function () {
  });
});
```

The problem is that this code will be triggered if the user clicks anywhere on the same line as the link, and not just on the link itself. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".question a")
```

You can use the selector part of Jquery quite creatively.  Searches all elements with class question and then selects all the a tags inside of it

If you want id, then switch to hash

```
$("#question a")
```